# how can we call the variable of js or jq in php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, json, html

can javascript or jquery variable can be read by php code?

Example

```
<script>
   var num = 3;
</script>
<php?
   $a = 20;
   $b = num*$a;
?>
```

anyone?

Comment: somany people http://goo.gl/XfFnC6

Comment: PHP - server side language; JS - client side language. What do you think?

Comment: If you want to process a variable on server,  consider using node.js.  Other than that, you are out of luck.  You can not directly access client side variables on server without a POST(or whatever!) request.  Considering the information you give in your question,  `$_POST` is your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - No it can't. But there is an alternative known as AJAX where you can send a javascript variable to a `php` page and make it accessible to that page. Consider the following example:

```
$.ajax({
   url:'some-php-page.php',
   type:'post',
   data:{num:3},
   success:function(data_returned)
   {
      // do anything you want with the data returned back
      alert(data_returned); // will alert 60
   }
});
```

**some-php-page.php**

```
$num = $_POST['num']; // the key used in the "data" attribute of the ajax call
$a = 20;
$b = $num*$a;
echo $b;
```

Of course you'll need to include [jQuery](https://jquery.com) library in order to use the [$.ajax({})](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). This can be done through plain javascript too, but I prefer to use jQuery as it is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is interpreted on the server. Javascript is interpreted in the browser. Since PHP cannot run after the HTTP request has been fulfilled and a response has been sent to the browser, it is not possible for PHP to access a javascript variable.

Comment: I don't agree,  this is not a complete answer.  client side variables can be accessed on server if they are sent with a `$_POST` request.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr - The data is copied and sent to the server. The server can process the data, but the server can never access client-side variables.